# JBoss Session Timeout

Tags: jboss, session-timeout

I'm trying to write the part of my app so that it handles session timeouts gracefully, but I can't seem to control how the duration of time before a timeout occurs for testing.

I am using JBoss 5.1, and I am modifying the session-config my web descriptor (web.xml) such that the session times out after a minute (just for testing)

```
<session-config>
  <session-timeout>1</session-timeout>
</session-config>
```

But after creating a session by logging in, it never times out.  No setting that I give it causes a timeout.

In a tomcat environment, I haven't had this problem.  Has anyone had a similar problem with JBoss?

Comment: Hi,
I am facing the same issue where I am using Jboss 5.1 server and my session timeout doesnt work.
I have tried the above steps by setting in deployers/jbossweb.deployer/web.xml  .
Also i tried by programmatically forcing the timeout using - HttpSession.setMaxInactiveInterval(int seconds)
But still it doesnt get timed out.

Please suggest

Answer (score 19, accepted):

JBoss 5 allows you to define a session timeout for all applications at:

```
deployers/jbossweb.deployer/web.xml
```

It may be that is overriding your settings in *web.xml*. It shouldn't, but, you know...

Check if changing that is working. If not, you can set up the timeout programatically for your test:

[HttpSession.setMaxInactiveInterval(int seconds)](http://java.sun.com/products/servlet/2.2/javadoc/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html)

That way you can force the timeout in a particular session.

Answer (score 8):

Sadly in JBoss EAP 6.1.0.Alpha1 (AS 7.2.0.Alpha1-redhat-4) we're back to having to set it per web app in web.xml: [See the JBoss docs](https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Web_Framework_Kit/2.2/html/Seam_Reference_Guide/ch27s07.html).

Which say use this:

```
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
</session-config>
```

Answer (score 0):

In case of some settings JBoss overrides the ones you provide in web.xml . You need to specify the same in a config file named "jboss-web.xml" to apply this setting. You can place this file next to the web.xml, in the same folder.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE xml>
<jboss-web>  
  <session-config>
    <session-timeout>1</session-timeout>
  </session-config>
</jboss-web>
```