# Change Session Timeout during runtime in Struts2

Tags: struts2, session-timeout

I know that I can set the session timeout in web.xml in the `<session-config>` section. What I need now is to change this setting dynamically during runtime, i.e. call a method that overrides the web.xml setting if needed.

Any ideas? I found nothing so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it! As described in [JBoss Session Timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3197438/jboss-session-timeout) one can use [HttpSession.setMaxInactiveInterval(int seconds)](http://java.sun.com/products/servlet/2.2/javadoc/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html).