# Session timeout not happening

Tags: java, session, servlets, web.xml

What are the steps to identify the session has timed out and to redirect it,i hav tried by giving session-timeout as 1 min in web.xml,whether that makes session to timout?

for redirecting in filter:

```
if (request.getRequestedSessionId() != null   && !request.isRequestedSessionIdValid()) 
        response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath() + "/login.html");
                    return;
    }
    else {
        response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-       revalidate"); // HTTP 1.1.
        response.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache"); // HTTP 1.0.
        response.setDateHeader("Expires", 0);
        filterChain.doFilter(servletRequest, servletResponse);
    }
```

but it not redirecting to login page,what am i missing here?

one more clarification needed is : does url-pattern tag in web.xml should hav the redirection page address?

```
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>SessionTimeoutCookieFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>login.html</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

any suggestion on this please....

Comment: It depend by your application server.
If you are using jboss [this should help you][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3197438/jboss-session-timeout

Answer (score 1):

Try this in your `web.xml` if you are using `Apache Tomcat`

```
         <session-config>
            <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
        </session-config>
```

Comment: ya we are using Apache Tomcat only. Have set the timeout as 1 min but its not working.                                         <session-config>
            <session-timeout>1</session-timeout>
        </session-config>

Answer (score 1):

It is very Simple. 
Add Following code into your **SessionTimeoutCookieFilter**

```
    HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
        if (null == session) {
            response.sendRedirect("index.jsp");
        }
```

And also change your url patern , something like i have used :-

```
<filter>
<filter-name>SessionFilter</filter-name>
 <filter-class>
    net.SessionFilter
</filter-class>
<init-param>
    <param-name>avoid-urls</param-name>
    <param-value>index.jsp</param-value>
</init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
 <filter-name>SessionFilter</filter-name>
 <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
 </filter-mapping>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>15</session-timeout>
</session-config>
```

or you can do using Java Code :

```
session.setMaxInactiveInterval(15 * 60); //15 minutes
```

The [HttpSession#setMaxInactiveInterval()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html#setMaxInactiveInterval%28int%29)  doesn't change much here by the way. It does exactly the same as `<session-timeout>` in `web.xml`, with the only difference that you can change/set it programmatically during `runtime`. The change by the way only affects the current session instance, not globally (else it would have been a `static` method).

```
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>-1</session-timeout>
</session-config>
```

You can use `-1` where the session never expires. Since you do not know how much time it will take for the thread to complete.

Comment: Thanks for the input,have set the timeout in session-config.But redirecting is not happening after the session timeout, here is where i'm.. Any idea ?

Comment: @user3485046 : look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15573221/redirecting-after-httpsession-time-out

Comment: @user3485046 : use filter, I haven't use this but look code http://www.jguru.com/forums/view.jsp?EID=1248692

Comment: I tried those ways too...but in vain
I want to know,when the session timeout happens do we need to make the session null or it will becom null automatically?
and what about the userid of that session,becomes null?

Comment: Yes it becomes null. So we don't have to do it manually, it automatically `invalidate()` to session.

Comment: thanks for the response
So it means if i set the time in web.xml and check the condition

if(session == null){
response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath() + "/login.html");
}

will redirect to login page after the session timeout?

Comment: Yes it will something like that.